# Define a function from a result of Series command in Maple

Tags: series, maple

Is there a simple way to define a function from a result of series command?
(that is, without the remainder term)

For example

`[> series(cos(x), x=0, 5);
              1-1/2*x^2+1/24*x^4+O(x^5)`

and I want to define a function

`[> f:=(x)->1-1/2*x^2+1/24*x^4;`

I don't know a simple way how to do it without manual copy/paste, I need to do it dynamically. At the moment the way I do it is really cumbersome:

`` [> S:=series(cos(x), x=0, 5);
   f:=unapply(`+`(seq(op(S)[2*k-1]*x^(op(S)[2*k]), k=1..nops(S)/2-1)), x); ``

In case of [generalized series requiring fractional exponents](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=series) I can do it this way:

`[> S:=series(sqrt(sin(x)), x=0, 4);
    f:=unapply(S-op(S)[nops(S)], x);`

I don't know a reliable way to combine both cases into one (the number of terms in the second case is similar to the order, while it's almost double in the first case, but it's not a reliable way since some functions might have very few terms even for high order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This methodology covers both examples in the same fashion.

```
restart;

S:=series(cos(x), x=0, 5);

                      1  2   1   4    / 6\
             S := 1 - - x  + -- x  + O\x /
                      2      24   

P:=convert(S, polynom);

                          1  2   1   4
                 P := 1 - - x  + -- x 
                          2      24   

F:=unapply(P, x);

                             1  2   1   4
               F := x -> 1 - - x  + -- x 
                             2      24   

F(0.3);

                      0.9553375000

cos(0.3);

                      0.9553364891
```

And the other,

```
restart;

S:=series(sqrt(sin(x)), x=0, 5);

         (1/2)   1   (5/2)    1    (9/2)    / (13/2)\
   S := x      - -- x      + ---- x      + O\x      /
                 12          1440                    

P:=convert(S, polynom);

               (1/2)   1   (5/2)    1    (9/2)
         P := x      - -- x      + ---- x     
                       12          1440       

F:=unapply(P, x);

                  (1/2)   1   (5/2)    1    (9/2)
       F := x -> x      - -- x      + ---- x     
                          12          1440       

F(0.3);

                      0.5436177192

sqrt(sin(0.3));

                      0.5436177027
```

You can see this step which you were missing (to `convert` to `polynom`), in the examples on the [help page](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=series) for `series` itself.